# Draw a line over images in javascript using Opencv.js

Tags: javascript, html, opencv

in this upload.html page the user will be upload multi images 
after that draw line on the images the show in the same page

**Note:
draw a line, not by the user**

this error appears  to me when i run a code

```
Uncaught 
BindingError
message: "Cannot pass "1" as a Mat"
name: "BindingError"
stack: "BindingError: Cannot pass "1" as a Mat↵    at BindingError.<anonymous>
```

A code

```
function preview_images() 
{

 var total_file=document.getElementById("images").files.length;

 for(var i=0;i<total_file;i++)
 {
  //cv.line(total_file, Point(dx+150, dy+100), Size(100,70), 0, 0, 360, white, -1, 8, 0 )

   cv.line(total_file, (20, 160), (100, 160), (0, 0, 255), 10) 


         var UrlFile=URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]);


  $('#image_preview').append("<div class='col-md-3'><img class='img-responsive' src='"+UrlFile+"'></div>");
 }

}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
 <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="col-md-6">

  <input type="file" class="form-control" id="images" name="images"  onchange="preview_images(this);" multiple="" accept='image/*' />


  <input type ="submit" value = "upload"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var img           = document.getElementById('img');
var canvas_output = document.getElementById("canvas_output");

var mat = cv.imread(img);
for (j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {
    let line = lines[j]
    // line = [y_1, x_1, y2, x_2]
    let y_1 = line[0]
    let x_1 = line[1]
    let y_2 = line[2]
    let x_2 = line[3]
    let p1  = new cv.Point(x_1, y_1);
    let p2  = new cv.Point(x_2, y_2);
    cv.line(mat, p1, p2, [0, 255, 0, 255], 1)
}

cv.imshow(canvas_output, mat);
mat.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you try to pass a number into a field that requires a Mat object.

cv.line(total_file, (20, 160), (100, 160), (0, 0, 255), 10) - where `total_file` is a number.

Please refer to the documentation provided by opencv: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga7078a9fae8c7e7d13d24dac2520ae4a2

As an example you could do

```
let matrix = new cv.Mat()

cv.line(matrix, (20, 160), (100, 160), (0, 0, 255), 10)
```

Comment: As the coordinates need to be specified by Point instances, and the color by an array, I think the line would look like the following:

`cv.line(matrix, new cv.Point(20, 160), new cv.Point(100, 160), [0, 0, 255, 255], 10)`